# How to start using Telerik in asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I want to try Telerik in my C# asp.MVC project. I downloaded and installed the Telerik for MVC and a new `Telerik` menu option shows in my Visual Studio 2010.

Now, I've searched for a while but I didn't find a step by step help on how to actually start using the Telerik controls.

Can someone help?

I took a look at [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/button/index) for a simple button but in my cshtml page the `@Html.Kendo` isn't recognized. I think that managing to use a simple button will allow me to use any other control.

Thanks

Comment: you have to add reference its dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, got the answer. I'm posting it here since it seems like others may benefit from it.

As @ken2k mentioned, in order to use the Telerik controls, developers must add references, include css and js, etc. However, that's theory and not practice. Furthermore, that's not enough as some other steps must be taken.

After stumbling for a while, I found the solution step by step, as I wanted (and assume any first time users want) in the link below.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-4

Thanks anyway to all helpers.

Comment: Do you have a more recent version?

Answer (score 2):

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/

This are all controls that you can use. In mvc Telerik controls are called kendo.
Its fairly very easy just add script and css and go.

download this project for your reference and add all dll, script and css which this project has used.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675879/An-Example-to-Use-Kendo-Grid

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new project using [their wizard](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/vs-integration/new-project-wizard).

It'll setup a new project for you with anything you need to start developing with their tools: required assemblies for the ASP.Net MVC extensions (the `@Html.Kendo` thing), CSS, javascripts...etc.

Comment: Already tried that and it didn't work. The default project wouldn't even compile. Anyway, I want to use the controls in an existing project

Comment: @chiapa You should have mentioned this in the original question. So to answer your second question: add the following in your project: a reference to the assembly Kendo.Mvc, all css and javascript coming from a template project created using the wizard, jquery scripts, kendo display/editor templates...etc. You have a "convert project wizard" that should do all this for you http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/vs-integration/convert-project-wizard (never tested it personally)

Comment: I did mention it, read carefully. I tried the convert option and didn't work well. The answer is what you say: add reference, css, js, etc etc. That's theory and I can't put into practice because I don't know where are those things or how to exactly do them

Comment: @chiapa No you didn't mentioned anything, read your question carefully. You talked about "your" C# project but it doesn't mean it already exists. You said you had a menu option but you didn't talked a second about having tried the wizards. You have not said creating a new project doesn't compile. By the way "didn't work well" doesn't mean anything useful.

Comment: @2ken2k, if I asked you "how can I buy a radio for my car?", you could assume the car already exists, don't you think? Or would you answer: "hey, buy a new car, it already comes with a radio in it".